# Node MSSQL can't insert array

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I want to insert many rows at once with an array data.

My array looks like this

```
[ [ '1234' ],
  [ '5678' ],
  [ '9123' ]... ]
```

and my query code

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'pass',
    server: 'ip',
    database: 'db'
};

async function get_numbers() {
    try {
        let pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();
        var qstring = `INSERT INTO numbers (gen_number) VALUES ?`;
        pool.request().query(qstring, mins, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        //pool.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

But this gives incorrect syntax near ? error.

Comment: Could you please write how should values be passed in case multiple columns and rows are being inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to insert the array contents `1234,5678 ..` into the db. You can use

the following query

```
var array = [ [ '1234' ], [ '5678' ],  [ '9123' ]... ];

var query = `var query = `INSERT INTO numbers (gen_number) VALUES ${array.join().split(",").map(i => '(' + i + ')').join()}``
```

This is simply joining the array contents and giving you a string that matches the `SQL` syntax to insert multiple values in one statement.

The above query will result into something like

```
"INSERT INTO numbers (gen_number) VALUES 1234,5678,9123"
```

Comment: but it needs to be like `"INSERT INTO numbers (gen_number) VALUES (1234),(5678),(9123)"`

Comment: In that case you should use `var query = `INSERT INTO numbers (gen_number) VALUES ${array.join().split(",").map(i => '(' + i + ')').join()}``

Comment: it worked thank you very much but does this also slows down my code because of extra overhead there? I,m passing between 50,000 to 1,500,000 number of elements via array

Comment: yeah that is extra overhead that comes at the cost of bad data formatting

Comment: This allows SQL injection! - "Those who fail to learn from history are doomed to repeat it!"

Answer (score 3):

The mssql library has a [bulk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk-table-callback) method for exactly this purpose.

```
const table = new sql.Table('numbers');
table.create = false; // presuming table already exists
table.columns.add('gen_number', sql.Int, { nullable: false });
// Add rows
numArr.forEach(x => table.rows.add(x));

const request = new sql.Request();
request.bulk(table, (err, result) => {
  // ... error checks
})
```

Comment: @ggnoredo I've used `gen_num` instead of `gen_number`, just updated

Comment: so i need to add column also? i passed that part because i already have column anyway this throws this error now `RequestError: Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 1.`  i used `sql.BigInt`

Comment: @ggnoredo it depends on the format of the column, what is the type of the column in the DB? I noticed in your example you have the numbers as string but I presumed you stored them as actual integers in the DB.

Comment: i didn't want to fill numbers in trillions but it's Bigint on Sql Server

Comment: @ggnoredo then you'll need to do `numArr.forEach(x => table.rows.add(parseInt(x, 10)))`